# Get data from a Firebase Realtime Database child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

This my project I have 2 RecyclewView, the first selects the user I want to manipulate, which is working perfectly. 
When selecting it I store your id and transfer it to a next screen that should show your medical history (using your id to search your database for your history).
But this recycler view remains blank, does not give an error but also does not return anything, maybe I'm missing the time to put the path to be taken to bring this history.

image BD Firestore: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBOml.jpg

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verificar_historico)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar_historico)
    toolbar_historico.setTitle("Titulo Aqui")

    userId = intent.extras?.getString("userId")


    textViewX.setText(userId)



    getLastKey()

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_view_historico.layoutManager = layoutManager

    val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(recycler_view_historico.context, layoutManager.orientation)
    recycler_view_historico.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)

    adapter = HistoricoAdapter(this)
    recycler_view_historico.adapter = adapter

    getHistorico()

    recycler_view_historico.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            total_item = layoutManager.itemCount
            last_visible_item = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

            if (isLoading && total_item <= last_visible_item + ITEM_COUNT) {
                getHistorico()
                isLoading = true
            }
        }
    })
}


private fun getHistorico() {
    if (!isMaxData) {
        val query: Query
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(last_node))
            query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("pacientes/$userId/historico")
                .orderByKey()
                .limitToFirst(ITEM_COUNT)
        else
            query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("pacientes/$userId/historico")
                .orderByKey()
                .startAt(last_node)
                .limitToFirst(ITEM_COUNT)

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if (p0.hasChildren()) {
                    val historicoLista = ArrayList<HistoricoRecycle>()
                    for (snapshot in p0.children)
                        historicoLista.add(snapshot.getValue(HistoricoRecycle::class.java)!!)
                    last_node = historicoLista[historicoLista.size - 1].data

                    if (!last_node.equals(last_key))
                        historicoLista.removeAt(historicoLista.size - 1)
                    else
                        last_node = "end"

                    adapter.addAll(historicoLista)
                    isLoading = false
                } else {
                    isLoading = false
                    isMaxData = true
                }
            }

        })
    }
}

private fun getLastKey() {

    val get_last_key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("pacientes/$userId/historico")
        .orderByKey()
        .limitToLast(1)
    get_last_key.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            for (userSnapShot in p0.children)
                last_key = userSnapShot.key
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Now im using:
            .child("pacientes").child(userId.toString()).child("historico")
without success...

Comment: Your code isn't querying Cloud Firestore - you're using Realtime Database.  I edited your question.  Perhaps you are simply using the wrong SDK to access to the wrong database product.

Comment: Please add your Firebase realtime database structure and please also responde with @

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks bro! Actually, I'm a beginner and I received a strong demand for my knowledge to develop an application using firebase. All solved, thank you!